# VirtualBox error while using Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I want to use Vagrant to create a virtual machine for a development environment. I am getting an error when it tries to install the virtual machine into VirtualBox. The output of VBoxManage import is below. My colleague is able to run this command without any problem. I am on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and he is on Debian.

Does anyone have an idea of the meaning of this error?

```
20:41:26:haitran:vagrant $  vagrant up
[default] Box ubuntu1104 was not found. Fetching box from specified URL...
[default] Downloading with Vagrant::Downloaders::HTTP...
[default] Downloading box: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7490647/talifun-ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.box
[default] Extracting box...
[default] Verifying box...
[default] Cleaning up downloaded box...
[default] Importing base box 'ubuntu1104'...
The VM import failed! Try running `VBoxManage import` on the box file
manually for more verbose error output.
21:06:54:haitran:vagrant $  VBoxManage import ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu1104/box.ovf 
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /Users/haitran/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu1104/box.ovf...
OK.
Disks:  vmdisk1 41943040000     -1      http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized       box-disk1.vmdk  -1      -1
Virtual system 0:
 0: Suggested OS type: "Ubuntu_64"
    (change with "--vsys 0 --ostype <type>"; use "list ostypes" to list all possible values)
 1: Suggested VM name "talifun-ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64"
    (change with "--vsys 0 --vmname <name>")
 2: Number of CPUs: 1
    (change with "--vsys 0 --cpus <n>")
 3: Guest memory: 360 MB
    (change with "--vsys 0 --memory <MB>")
 4: Network adapter: orig NAT, config 2, extra slot=0;type=NAT
 5: CD-ROM
    (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 5 --ignore")
 6: IDE controller, type PIIX4
    (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 6 --ignore")
 7: IDE controller, type PIIX4
    (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 7 --ignore")
 8: SATA controller, type AHCI
    (disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 8 --ignore")
 9: Hard disk image: source image=box-disk1.vmdk, target path=/Users/haitran/VirtualBox VMs/talifun-ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64/box-disk1.vmdk, controller=8;channel=0
    (change target path with "--vsys 0 --unit 9 --disk path";
    disable with "--vsys 0 --unit 9 --ignore")
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the clone medium '/Users/haitran/VirtualBox VMs/talifun-ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_GENERAL_FAILURE)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Appliance, interface IAppliance, callee 
Context: "ImportAppliance" at line 793 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Comment: Were you able to find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Seems the question has been sitting here for a while, so maybe you already solved the problem. We're also using Vagrant and run into a strange problem where the box was corrupted.

For us this caused the provisioning to fail on a given laptop, but work on all the others. There was no clear indication of the failure, besides the provisioning process just froze.

Have you checked the sha1-sum or similar, to verify that you have exactly the same box file downloaded as your colleague? All the disk image files are cached under ~/.vagrant.d/boxes, so you could compare the checksums under that directory, right after import.

Comment: This answer is 3 years old. I have reasons to think that I face a similar problem. Any other, newer findings/hints, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't downloaded the box yet, so vagrant is doing it's best to find the original location of the box.

Try downloading the box manually

```
vagrant box add ubuntu1104  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7490647/talifun-ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.box
```

Also try turning up the logging

$ VAGRANT_LOG=DEBUG vagrant up

http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/debugging.html

Lastly, try a different box image. It may have an newer/older version of virtual box guest editions installed. Could explain why your colleague has no issues with it.